# Gathering Google Account data using ID

Tags: php, api, openid

I want to allow users to log into my site using their Google accounts. I want to be able to get their session; if they have actually logged in, their email and their google name.

I current have a log in system for Google which works perfectly and once they are signed in it give out this code

"User https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawlaxJIBB-bwC8Yc49r5GNNRsdQiD1Fs2dU has logged in."

I want to know how to get their account information like their email from this id, if the id is correct that is.

Comment: The Google documentation is not useful for you?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't. It's a privacy thing.  The best you can do is ask them for the information later.